# Difference between coupling with bridge and router

Tags: router, tcp, lan, bridge

(warning: this is an old exam question, for which I don't have a solution):

Assume 2 local networks LAN1 and LAN2, with Endsystems A,C in LAN1 and B,D in LAN2. The networks are coupled with a bridge. 
Assume A wants to send a TCP Frame to B. Which address information does it need to contain? List all headers of OSI Layers 2-4, take sender and receiver into account.

What my solution would be:

TCP Port A -> IP-A -> Mac-A -> Mac-Bridge -> Mac-B -> IP-B -> TCP-Port-B
is that correct?

If I used a Router instead of the bridges and LAN1 and LAN2 are seperate IP-Subnetworks, would the difference be:

TCP Port A -> IP-A -> Mac-A -> Mac-Bridge -> IP-Bidge-> Mac-Bridge -> Mac-B -> IP-B -> TCP-Port-B?

Or what would change here? Am I understanding this correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a homework question? What's the application you're building or problem you're solving?

Comment: Like I said on top: I'm preparing for an exam, this is an old exam question for which there is no official solution. I would like to verify my understanding of the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packet will contain

Case 1 - No routing - PC A send packet directly to PC B

- source TCP port
- destination TCP port
- source IP address :  IP address of A
- destination IP address : IP address of B
- source MAC addres : MAC address of A
- destination MAC address: MAC address of B (obtained trough an ARP request on B IP address)

Case 2 - With router - the PC A send the packet to its gateway (I.E. the router)

- source TCP port
- destination TCP port
- source IP address :  IP address of A
- destination IP address : IP address of B
- source MAC addres : MAC address of A
- destination MAC address: MAC address of the router (obtained trough an ARP request on the router IP address. I.E. the IP configured as defaut gateway on A)

Comment: Assuming LAN1 and LAN2 are different subnets, with no router to allow traffic between subnets, then in Case 1 PCa won't send the traffic to PCb. It will want to send the traffic to a gateway or if no gateway is configured give a "no route to host" result.